# How do I extract strings from exe file in Python using windows?

Tags: windows

How to extract strings from executable file in Python using windows.....when I do it in the django python it give me an error
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5ii2.png)

Comment: You could use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (wsl.exe), then use the `strings` command

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: can you please explain this\

Comment: extremely late, but refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install